# How to make a secure blog that is completely private?

Tags: comments, spam, blog, private

I have a login safe application and it has hundreds of users.
WordPress is a separate module of it and only used for blogging purpose [no other usage]. 
Both using the common database.
The blogs are not for public but only for our users.

Recently I am getting spam comments to our blogs and I am worried about the blogs.

How I can make the WordPress totally private for our application users. All our users do not have WordPress login but are allowed to check the blogs and post their comments.

Comment: If you already have "a login safe application and […] WordPress is a separate module of it", then Wordpress should be hidden behind the apps login. If someone has access to your plugged-in Wordpress, the he/she has also access to your whole application, or not?!

Comment: In my application wordpress is a separate entity. In my application I only used the link of blogs. I need that to be part of my application and should be visible after people logged in my application.

Answer (score 1):

If your on a company intranet it might be easier/more secure to just whitelist a few IP's and deny access to everything else, you can do that with apache config or .htaccess. Otherwise you will have to get people to login and then you can use a plugin like "Members Only", there are several of these for private blogs.

Comment: My application is online...not in intranet. My users are accessing that from different cities. So IP blocking not possible, For "Members Only" plugin, how WordPress can identify my application users? It is not possible to create account in WordPress for each user.

Comment: Then you will have to get them to login, or create logins for them and email them the info.

Comment: can I use any how our session Ids which are created during our application login?

Comment: No, WordPress does not use sessions, though I think there are some hacks that enable it.

Comment: do you mean custom editing in php?

Answer (score 1):

if you are worried about spams you should use a anti-spam plugin (Akismet comes by default you should configure it). For the session enabling and usage you [wordpress session enabler](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-session-enabler/) (but i highly dough that it would be of much help). You can also use [Registered Users Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registered-users-only/), [Members Only](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members-only/) or [registered users only 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/registered-users-only-2/) to force your users to login before the can access your blog if you can configure your app and wp use the same user db. And be sure that you have told wp to stay private and hidden from search engines some times that also helps against spam.